# ScrollView touch forwarding to UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

What I'm trying to do is lay a scrollview overtop of the navigationBar but still have the navigation bar get touch input.

I've looked at the responder chain and the bar doesn't seem to be in it.

```
FowardScrollView* _scrollView = [[FowardScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 480.0f, 40.0f)];


UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: [[UIViewController alloc] init] ];
navController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"hello world" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
[navController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview: navController.view];

[self.view addSubview: _scrollView];
```

Then in the forward view's imp

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
//    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get at the actual touch event, say, to forward it to the navigation bar, you could always override `UIApplication` and its touch processing methods.